# Lighttpd How do i disable directly access my website by ip and name server?

Tags: apache, server, lighttpd, dedicated-server

Recently i just found that my website can access by IP and name server.
My server using Lighttpd and closed Apache service.So i don't know how to disable access direct by ip and name server on Lighttpd.

I have closed all of Apache service such as httpd, mod_userdir tweak and etc. I've tried to editing code in mod_userdir.conf file but still not work.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to deny access to all requests which are not http://valid-hostname.example.com/...

    `$HTTP["host"] != "valid-hostname.example.com" {
        url.access-deny = ("")
    }`

https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Docs_ModAccess